# Insert Null value To an inet field in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, notnull

I am trying to insert values to a table which contains two columns with `inet` types. When I try to insert a `NULL` value to these columns I get an error saying

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type inet: ""

Actually I am triyng to do this from python using sqlalchemy but naturally I get the same error saying:

> Session.commit() error: (DataError)
>   invalid input syntax for type inet: ""

I need to be able to add null values to these columns.
These colums do not have an attribute like `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message seems to indicate you are using an empty string to indicate a "null" value which is not correct.

The following should work:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (inet_column) VALUES (NULL);
```

Or if you actually mean update instead of insert:

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET inet_column = NULL
WHERE pk_column = 42;
```